# How do I point an argument and then after that one, execute another one?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm a beginner with Python and I'm trying to do a music bot for a friend's Discord. My problem is when I use the command `.play` the bot, if not kicked from the vocal chat, doesn't accept any new song to play. It's frustrating each time kicking it and then redo `.play` command.

This is my code so far:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.webm")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.webm")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
        return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='Appalacchia on the Road')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': '249/250/251',

    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".webm"):
            os.rename(file, "song.webm")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.webm"))
```

In the last string it would be perfect something like this:

```py
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.webm") THEN voice.disconnect())
```

So after the song is played, the bot automatically left the voice chat.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanx in advance to everyone!